# mysql query does not display the right output

Tags: php, mysql

I have this `mysqli` query that will display all the data that the `crew_status` is `PENDING FOR LINEUP` but with my `query` right now, it displays all the `data` that is in `database`

Here is my `query`:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';
include 'header.php';

    $master = 'MASTER';
    $chck = 'CHCK';
    $second_engineer = '2E';
    $second_mate = '2M';
    $third_engineer = '3E';
    $third_mate = '3M';
    $ce = 'CE';
    $bsn = 'BSN';
    $ab = 'AB';
    $olr = 'OLR';
    $dcdt = 'DCDT';
    $egdt = 'EGDT';
    $cook = 'COOK';
    $messman = 'MESSMN';
    $crew_status = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? AND `crew_status` = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssssss', $crew_status, $master, $chck, $second_engineer, $second_mate, $third_engineer, $third_mate, $ce, $bsn, $ab, $olr, $dcdt, $egdt, $cook, $messman);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $age, $month, $day, $year, $birth_place, $gender, $martial_status, $religion, $nationality, $email_address, $address_1, $address_2, $course, $school_graduated, $remarks, $note, $date_added, $crew_status, $crew_rank, $image_name, $updated_photo, $passport_registration, $passport_expiration);



?>
```

Can someone tell what is the problem?

```
    <?php

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".sprintf("%s%s%s", $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".sprintf("%s", $crew_rank)."</td>";
        echo "<td>".sprintf("%s", $crew_status)."</td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: cover all OR conditions for crew_rank in () and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `or` with `(`, `)`, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `crew_info`
WHERE (
    `crew_rank` = 'MASTER'
    OR `crew_rank` = 'CHCK'
    OR `crew_rank` = 'MESSMN'
    OR `crew_rank` = '2E'
    OR `crew_rank` = '2M'
    OR `crew_rank` = 'COOK'
    OR `crew_rank` = 'OLR'
    OR `crew_rank` = 'AB'
    OR `crew_rank` = '3E'
    OR `crew_rank` = '3M')
AND `crew_status` = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP'
```

Without `()`, if one of these `OR`s matches, then condition left will not be computed.

See this:

```
true || false && false = true 
(true || false) && false = false
```

And I think you'd better use `IN` instead of `OR` like :

```
SELECT *
FROM `crew_info`
WHERE 
    `crew_rank` IN ('MASTER','CHCK','MESSMN','2E','2M','COOK','OLR','AB','3E','3M')
AND `crew_status` = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP'
```

***Edited:***

```
SELECT *
FROM `crew_info`
WHERE (crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ? OR crew_rank = ?)
AND crew_status = ?
```

Comment: can you explain me this one? why my query does not display the right output and yours displays the right output?

Comment: how to do this in `mysqli prepared` ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? OR `crew_rank` = ? AND `crew_status` = ?` how can I do that in my code?

Comment: OK, here you just give us sql query, but no php code. I can't do more than this. @aronpascua

Comment: No, code like so does not make sense. You should post more about this query.

Comment: i added all my codes. im really sorry can you please check it again? @JPG

Comment: @aronpascua Ask a new question please, you have some errors in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE (`crew_rank` = 'MASTER' OR `crew_rank` = 'CHCK' OR `crew_rank` = 'MESSMN' OR `crew_rank` = '2E' OR `crew_rank` = '2M' OR `crew_rank` = 'COOK' OR `crew_rank` = 'OLR' OR `crew_rank` = 'AB' OR `crew_rank` = '3E' OR `crew_rank` = '3M') AND (`crew_status` = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP')
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The ANDs and ORs are ambiguous. It's unclear if you want something like:

```
(A AND B) OR C
```

or

```
A AND (B OR C)
```

Add some parenthesis to clear things up:

```
SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE (`crew_rank` = 'MASTER' OR `crew_rank` = 'CHCK' OR `crew_rank` = 'MESSMN' OR `crew_rank` = '2E' OR `crew_rank` = '2M' OR `crew_rank` = 'COOK' OR `crew_rank` = 'OLR' OR `crew_rank` = 'AB' OR `crew_rank` = '3E' OR `crew_rank` = '3M') AND `crew_status` = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `crew_rank` IS NOT NULL AND `crew_status` = 'PENDING FOR LINEUP'
I hope this would be worked.